# Probability of finding P(X=k)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A factory produces 10 glass containers daily. It may be assumed that there is a constant probability p=0.1 of producing a defective container. Before these containers are stored they are inspected and the defectives ones are set aside. Suppose that there is a constant probability r=0.2 that a defective container is misclassified. Let X equal the number of containers classified as a defective at the end of a production day. (Suppose that all containers which are manufactured on a particular day are also inspected on that day.)

(1)P(X=k) = ?

Comment: Defective = (P intersectionof(not r)) + (r intersectionof(not p)).
p and r are independent events, so,
P(defective) = (p)(not r) + (not p)(r) = (.1)(.8) + (.9)(.2) = .08 + .18 = .26 ?
Then what we can do for finding P(X=k)?

Comment: What is the probability that non-defective container is misclassified?

Comment: suppose,it may happen that calculating defective item as Non-Defective item or vice-versa(is called misclassified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording of the problem is unfortunately ambiguous. But we lean to the interpretation that **if** a container is defective, there is a probability  $0.2$ that the containder is classified as non-defective.  **Nothing** is said about classification errors on non-defectives. So we will assume that a non-defective is always classified as non-defective.

Thus the probability that a container is set aside is $(0.1)(0.8)=0.08$. Call this number $p$.

Then the number of containers set aside has **binomial** distribution. The probability that this number is $k$ is $\dbinom{10}{k}p^k(1-p)^{10-k}$.

**Remark:** The problem *could* be interpreted as meaning that with probability $0.2$, a container is **misclassified**. (But the problem does not *say* that.) In that case, a container can be set aside for two disjoint reasons: (i) It is defective, and correctly set aside or (ii) it is OK, but wrongly set aside. Then the probability of being set aside is $(0.1)(0.8)+(0.9)(0.2)=0.26$. The rest of the calculation would be as above, with $p=0.26$.

Comment: Oh.. Got it!! Thanks..

Comment: You are welcome. It would be unreasonable to ask this question before the binomial distribution is introduced, so I assumed the basic formula was already familiar.

Comment: It wold have een better to ask it as a question, editing in comments is tough, and I am typo-prone. But here goes. $\Pr(Y\le k)=\Pr(1-X\le k)=\Pr(X\ge 1-k)=1-\Pr(X\lt 1-k)=1-\Pr(X\le 1-k)$. (The last because continuous). We want this to be $0.25$, so we want $\Pr(X\le 1-k)=0.75$. By what we were given, $1-k=0.29$. So $k=0.71$. There is a nicer way of doing it, by appeal to symmetry.